# Proof of the Formula of the Principle of Non-Contradiction

Tags: logic, solution-verification, proof-explanation, propositional-calculus

I'm starting to study logic and I just found this exercise:

> 1. In these exercises you start from the axioms and must arrive at the
>    requested formula. The use of the The Deduction Theorem is not
>    allowed.
>
>    1. c. Prove the following theorem using only Kleene's axioms and the rule of
>       Modus Ponens. You are not allowed to use any additional theorems.
>
>       ⊢ ~( A ∧ ~A ) (Principle of Non-Contradiction)

This are the 8 axioms I need to work with:

```
├ A → ( B → A)
├ (A → B) → ((A → (B → (B → C) ) → (A → C))
├ A → (B → A ∧ B)
├ A ∧ B → A,,    A ∧ B → B
├ A → A ∨ B,,    B → A ∨ B
├ (A → C) → ((B → C ) → (A ∨ B → C))
├ (A → B) → (( A → ~B) → ~A )
├ ~~A → A
```

I understand the intuition behind the Principle of Non-Contradiction, but cannot figure out where to start with the proof.

I have done this, using the identity theorem which is not allowed in the exercise:

> ```
> ├ A → A
> ├ ~(~(A → A))
> ├ ~(~(A → ~~A))
> ~(A → ~B) ↔ A ∧ B
> ~( A ∧ ~A )
> ```

Is this proof valid? Although I am using the identity theorem I would like to know if this is a valid demonstration or am I doing something wrong. I have a second question, how would this exercise be done without using theorems?

Comment: Use the last but one Axiom strating from $A \land \lnot A$

Comment: IMO your attempted proof is not correct; with what rule you derived $\vdash \sim ( \sim (A → A))$ in the first step?

Comment: And what about the third step: $\sim (A → \sim B) ↔ A ∧ B$ ? There are no rules for $↔$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA you are right,  in order to derive ⊢∼(∼(A→A)) I tried to use double negation from ├ A → A. But that should be ⊢∼(∼(A→A))→ (A→A) if I'm not wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mauro Allegranza has already pointed out that your argument is extremely flawed; you use the operator ${\leftrightarrow}$ which is undefined in this logical calculus.  Here's a solution from scratch.

The outermost operation in $\neg(A\wedge\neg A)$ is ${\neg}$, so let's start by figuring out how that can arise.  The only axiom with ${\neg}$ in the conclusion is axiom 7: $$\vdash(a\to b)\to((a\to\neg b)\to\neg a)$$  So let's try that.  Comparing, we'll need $a=A\wedge\neg A$, but are free to choose $b$.  I'll figure out what $b$ needs to be later, and then come back and pencil it in.

To get $\neg a$ out of axiom 7, we'll need to use *modus ponens* a bunch.  So we also need \begin{gather*}
\vdash A\wedge\neg A\to b \\
\vdash A\wedge\neg A\to\neg b \tag{*}
\end{gather*}  Luckily, axiom 4 matches that schema: changing variable names to avoid confusion, axiom 4 says \begin{gather*}
\vdash x\wedge y\to x \\
\vdash x\wedge y\to y
\end{gather*}  So let's take $x=A$, $y=\neg A$; then we have \begin{gather*}
\vdash A\wedge\neg A\to A \\
\vdash A\wedge\neg A\to\neg A
\end{gather*}  Comparing with (*), we see that we should have chosen $b=A$.

Putting it all together, we have:

1. $\vdash A\wedge\neg A\to A$ (Axiom 4)
2. $\vdash A\wedge\neg A\to\neg A$ (Axiom 4)
3. $\vdash(A\wedge\neg A\to A)\to((A\wedge\neg A\to\neg A)\to\neg(A\wedge\neg A))$ (Axiom 7)
4. $\vdash(A\wedge\neg A\to\neg A)\to\neg(A\wedge\neg A)$ (Step 1, Step 3, MP)
5. $\vdash\neg(A\wedge\neg A)$ (Step 2, Step 4, MP)

Comment: Big +1 for motivation. Don't you mean modus ponens instead of modus tollens?

Comment: @Milten: I do.  Thanks!

Comment: I was also pleased by this answer.  Often people post proofs of this sort with no explanation of how to find them.  Someone reading this answer might come away having learned something.

Comment: @MJD: I'm glad you like it.  I posted this answer precisely because that sort of dry, insightless solution bothers me too, and I saw a chance to avert such an occurrence here.